# Why we need Predicate functional interface in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, predicate, functional-interface

Why we need Predicate interface? I didn't understand below code. How can I find result of primaryPaxOutput alternatively?

```
    Predicate<TravellerType> predicate1 = new Predicate<TravellerType>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(TravellerType input) {
            return PassengerCodeUtil.paxCodesEqual(input.getTravellerType().getCode(), "CHD");
        }
    };

    primaryPaxOutput = Iterables.tryFind(result.getTravellerTypes(), predicate1).orNull();
```

Comment: What do you think what this `Predicate` is doing?

Comment: this is the `guava` predicate btw, not jdk

Comment: @Eugene Both Interfaces have the same purpose.

Comment: @Flown I know...

Comment: Predicates tell you if a condition is true or false. Sounds handy if you're filtering a collection in a functional way.

Answer (score 4):

`Predicate`s are great for abstracting out entire functions into whatever type of result they produce, which increases readability and reusability. This is true for both Guava and Java versions of the interface. `Predicate`s should be well-named, so in this example it's a bit hard to understand what's going on.

I have no idea what a `TravellerType` or `PassengerCode` is, but for the sake of argument let's rename the `Predicate` to whatever it does.

We can then code our iterables statement to be:

```
primaryPaxOutput = Iterables.tryFind(result.getTravellerTypes(), paxCodeIsCHD).orNull();
```

We then interpret this statement as:

```
Iterables.tryFind(            //Find the first instance
result.getTravellerTypes(),   //among this Iterable
paxCodeIsCHD                  //where this predicate is true
).orNull();                   //or else set to null.
```

If you know what `tryFind` does, then this code becomes much more readable than injecting an anonymous class or even a lambda as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`Iterables.tryFind` will return first value in given list (`result.getTravellerTypes()`) which fulfills predicate given by parameter.

So for each of your travellerTypes it will run `apply` method. First which will return `true` will be returned by `tryFind` method.

`.orNull()` indicates, that if none objects in your list fulfills predicate method will return null instead optional.

Answer (score 0):

Predicates allow to set a condition during filtering.

Here your condition is :

```
PassengerCodeUtil.paxCodesEqual(input.getTravellerType().getCode(), "CHD");
```

It means you want to find the first `TravellerType` instance contained in `result.getTravellerTypes()`  which the `code` value is equal to the `CHD` String.

Without predicate usage that filters the expected element,  which interest to use `tryFind()` ? 
You may get any element in `result.getTravellerTypes()`.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8, Predicate is a functional interface which can be used as the assignment target for a lambda expression or method reference. So, where you think, we can use these true/false returning functions in day to day programming? I will say you can use predicates anywhere where you need to evaluate a condition on group/collection of similar objects such that evaluation can result either in true or false.

For example, you can use predicates in these real-time use cases

1. Find all children born after a particular date
2. Employees greater than a certain age and so on..